# Visual studio code will not let me push anything to my repository

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I have created on online repository on github and the repository is set to private. I have some files that i wish to commit and push to this repository using visual studio code. I have successfully cloned the repository to my local device after making the repository public but as soon as I wish to commit any of my changes i get the following error

```
Git remote: permission denied to <My username>
```

I have tried entering the following command in the terminal. The username is the username of the person who created the repository.

```
 git config --global user.name <github userID>
```

But the same error still persists. Like i said the user Id i enter created the repository and i am unsure why it is denying me access to the repository. Do i need to login on visual studio code with my github account and if so how do i do that.

Comment: You probably won't be able to use the UserId of repository creator -- unless they gave you their credentials, password included.  But if you are close enough to the creator of the repo to have them telling you their credential information then why not just have them add your GitHub account as a contributor with commit rights?  Perhaps you just want to create your modifications in a FORK of the original repo and commit the changes to the FORK in your own repo?

Comment: Hi david I created the repository and this is my account i am logging in to,. Sorry should have been more clear on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user.name` setting has nothing to do with authentication, only with commit authorship.

Check first your `git remote -v` output in your local repository.

If it is an SSH URL, and if [`ssh -Tv git@github.com` is working](https://help.github.com/en/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection)  (meaning you have registered your public key on your GItHub account and you see "`Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`"), that should work from VSCode too.

If it is an HTTPS URL, the first push from VSCode should trigger a popup, for you to enter your username/password.
Note: if you have [2FA activated](https://help.github.com/en/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa), that would be your username/[PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)

That should then be cached by your credential helper (check `git config --global credential.helper`)

Comment: Hi VonC it returns a HTTP URL

Comment: But i never receive the Popup to enter a username or password

Comment: @carlteunen HTTPS URL then? Check your credential helper, and see if you can update the cached credentials (https://help.github.com/en/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git). What OS are you using, with which version of Git?

Comment: Windows 10 when i run the Credential helper nothing pops up. I downloaded version 2.23.0 from the git website

Comment: I was able to clone the reeepository but only after i set the entire repository to public. If i set i to private then it simply said repository not found

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes I am on windows 10. Thank you for your help

Comment: Then check the GitHub link, and open your Windows credential Manager